# how to reconstruct this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

The `service_option` table and the `room` table have a same column `room_key`, the `room` table and the `user` table share a same column `user_key`, what I want is obtaining user's infomation from service options.

```
SELECT user_key, user_id, user_status, user_company_name
FROM user
WHERE user_key
IN (
    SELECT user_key
    FROM room
    WHERE room_key
    IN (
        SELECT room_key
        FROM service_option
        WHERE service_option_key = 3 AND ordered_service_option_status !=0
       )
    )
```

Using IN nested in another IN turned to be very inefficient.

Comment: [SQL JOIN](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT U.user_key
     ,U.user_id
     ,U.user_status
     ,U.user_company_name
FROM [user] U
INNER JOIN room R ON R.user_key = U.user_key
INNER JOIN service_option S ON S.room_key = R.room_key
                              AND S.service_option_key = 3
                              AND S.ordered_service_Option_status != 0
```

The `INNER JOIN` approach will be much more performant and make the query more readable.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It helps. and I added DISTINCT after SELECT

Answer (score 2):

Do not use WHERE IN, but join :

```
SELECT u.user_key, u.user_id, u.user_status, u.user_company_name
FROM user u, room r, service_option so
WHERE u.user_key = r.user_key 
AND r.room_key = so.room_key 
AND so.service_option_key = 3 
AND so.ordered_service_option_status != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.user_key, u.user_id, u.user_status, u.user_company_name
FROM 
user u join room r on u.user_key = r.user_key
join service_option so on so.room_key = r.room_key 
WHERE 
so.service_option_key = 3 AND so.ordered_service_option_status !=0
```